# Out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm getting the error in the title when I do this:

```
@shop.update(carrier_id: new_carrier_service.id)
```

`new_carrier_service.id` is a `FixNum`

In my postgresql db, `carrier_id` is: `t.integer  "carrier_id",        limit: 8`

And then when I go into the postgres console, and look up the `carrier_id` field, PG says its a `bigint`

And then if I just open up a Rails console, and update the field manually I don't get an error and the field is updated fine.

The migration that changed the field from an `integer` to a `bigint` is this:

```
class FixShopsCarrierIdUpDownAgain < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :shops, :carrier_id, :integer, limit: 8
  end

  def down
    change_column :shops, :carrier_id, :integer, limit: 4
  end
end
```

I can't figure out what's going on..

Comment: what is the `new_carrier_service.id` value? are the examples both console and the initial one run in the same environment?

Comment: Its just a long number, like this for example: 66322451 and its a `FixNum` when it comes over..this is an api call

Comment: rails version number?

Comment: Rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I would try to `change_column` to `bigint` instead of `integer, limit: 8`.

Comment: Try to update rails because this seems to be known problem https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20428